# Prove that an element of a quotient ring of polynomials is algebraic

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $K=\Bbb{Z}/5\mathbb {Z}$ and $L={\Bbb{Z}/5\mathbb Z[T]\over(T^2+3)}$. Prove that $L$ is a field. Then, let $a=[T+2]\in L$. Prove that a is algebraic over $K$.

I proved that $L$ is a field, since $T^2+3$ has no roots in $\Bbb{Z}/5\mathbb Z$, hence is irreducible. I don't know how to solve the second request, maybe I didn't understand enough the theory.

Comment: Can you first prove that $b = [t] \in L$ is algebraic over $K$ ?

Comment: For $\mathbb Z_5$ you mean $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$

Comment: non 5-adic numbers on $\mathbb Z$

Comment: Let me just clarify how much I know about the theory. If $K'$ is a field extension of a field $K$, an element $\alpha \in K'$ is said algebraic if it is a root of a non-zero polynomial in $K[X]$.  So to prove that $a=[t+2] \in L$ is algebraic over $K$, I need to show that there is a polynomial $f(t) \in K$ such that $f(a)=0$. I'm a little bit confused on how a class of polynomials can be a root of one polynomial.  With $\Bbb{Z}_5$ I mean the modular ring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just have to find $f(x)\in K[x]:f(T+2)=0$, where the polynomial itself cancels out using only coefficients from the field $K$ and the equivalence relation $T^3+3=0$.

$$(T+2)^3=T^3+6T^2+12T+8$$
$$(T+2)^2=T^2+4T+4$$
$$(T+2)^1=T+2$$
$$(T+2)^0=1$$

Now we can just use Gaussian elimination on this or something to come up with the coefficients $$f(x)=x^3-6x^2+12x-11$$

Answer (score 0):

If $K$ is a field and $f(T)\in K[T]$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $d$, then $K[T]/(f(T))$ is a field containing $K$ and
$$
\bigl[K[T]\big/(f(T)):K\bigr]=d
$$
Any finite extension of a field is algebraic: indeed, if $u\in F$, a finite extension of $K$ of degree $d$, the powers $\{1,u,u^2,\dots,u^d\}$ form a linearly dependent set over $K$.